# Code outputs NULL instead of value

Tags: java

The code suppose to print names entered by user but it is just printing the null values instead of printing actual names. I am using array to store the names values.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class PrintName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int nameCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " how many NAMES you want to enter?"));
         String [] userFirstName = new String [nameCount];
         String [] userLastName = new String [nameCount];
         for (int i=0; i<nameCount; i++) {
             fullName(userFirstName[i], userLastName[i]);
         }

         for (int i=0; i<nameCount; i++) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userFirstName[i] + "\n" + userLastName[i]);
    }

    public static void fullName (String firstName, String nLastName) {
        firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your first name?");
        nLastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your last name?");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that happen because you change the value and not the value pointer, change the firm of fullName for this:

```
public static void fullName (String[] firstName, String[] nLastName, int i) {
    firstName[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your first name?");
    nLastName[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your last name?");
}
```

And now you can call the function with this way:

```
fullName(userFirstName, userLastName, i);
```

I hope this works for you :)

Comment: @tonylattke I just modified the code with your given solution but I am still getting the null output

Comment: i was reading this link http://jagonzalez.org/usar-joptionpane-en-java/ and the call to the funcion JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your first name?"); is the problem you have to call without the null parameter, so the right call is this JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your first name?");

Comment: @tonylattke It still doesn't solve the problem. I am again getting null output. http://oi50.tinypic.com/10i8jts.jpg

Comment: The first function maybe is the problem too, call without the null parameter, so your first instruction is this: int nameCount = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" how many NAMES you want to enter?"));

Comment: @tonylattke i just tried that as well. it doesn't work either :(

Comment: @user2178940 what?? that works fine for me.. check out http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2wnzapu&s=6

Comment: @user2178940 -  I was about to say the same. The original solution posted by **tony** is correct and it works for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the names you entered and fetched in your `fullName()` are not reflected in the actual arrays `userFirstName`, `userLastName`.

The reason being, its a `pass by value`. You are passing a copy of your `userFirstName[i]` everytime(which is actually `null`), to your `fullName()` method, and modifying the local copy there. The changes made to `firstName` and `nLastName` won't be reflected back to your `userFirstName` array.

One thing you could do to fix it is this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameCount; i++) {
    userFirstName[i] = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog(null, "What's your first name?");
    userLastName[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's your last name?");
}
```

Getting the values in the `main()` method, within the `for` loop.

Comment: Could you please suggest a solution please?

Comment: @Tushar its simple, those fetched names are not being returned or assigned to the array that `should` contain those names

Comment: @user2178940 - check the updated answer. I've given a solution.

Comment: Check out @tonylattke's answer. Better than mine!

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ I'm aware of that. I just prefer answers that both explain and provide a solution to the OP. +1 R.J. for adding an explanation.

Comment: @R.J  Guys I am still getting the same error after following tonylattke's solution. http://oi47.tinypic.com/2i0xi7n.jpg

Comment: @R.J What have you done..? Haven't you tried IDE as you have suggested me...Don't be there in a feeling that others persons don't know anything..OK.

Comment: @Pragnani - can you highlight a bit more as to which thing in my code snippet is faulty? Because, I only post answers after checking it in the IDE. And you'd be thankful that I helped u correct the mistake, than SHOUT @ me.

Comment: @R.J I am not shouting you brother. Instead I was thankful to you. But your suggestion to IDE seems to be harsh..That gives other person negative feeling

Comment: @Pragnani - Trust me. Even I thought same when I was given this suggestion sometime back. But later I realized, how true and useful that was. Anyways, Cheers!